# Python - Returning Exception in unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, tdd

im starting to learn TDD and got the Bowling Game kata as exercise.
I have completed some of the regular score test, but i want to add more just to practice and one idea was to raise an exception if i roll a negative number.

The hole code is not relevant because this is a simple validation

```
class BowlingGame(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def roll(self, pins):
        if pins < 0:
            #Want to Return Value Exception

class BowlingGameTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self._game = BowlingGame()
    def test_roll_negative(self):
        self.game.roll(-1)
        #Want to catch exception here with self.assert or except
```

The problem is that if i return for example 0/0 the exception is raised in the BowlingGame class and not in the BowlingGameTest class (there are in two diferent files).

If i do `return ValueError` (BowlingGame Class) with `self.assertRaises(ValueError):` (BowlingGameTest Class) i got `AssertionError: ValueError not raised`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `raise` `ValueError` instead of `return`ing it, i.e.,

```
def roll(self, pins):
    if pins < 0:
        raise ValueError
```

*Returning* an exception actually returns the class object, but if you *raise* an exception, it will throw an error like you want.

It sounds like you're using `self.assertRaises` correctly - just in case though - it should look like this:

```
def test_roll_negative(self):
    with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
        self.game.roll(-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this ..

```
try:
    self.game.roll(-1)
except ValueError:
    pass
```